# Iron Router: Load js script after template has been rendered

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to load a javascript file (using IRLibloader) after the Iron Router has rendered the template:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
});

Router.route('/', {
  name: 'landing',
  template: 'landing',
  onBeforeAction: function () {
    var googleAPI = IRLibLoader.load('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false');
    var fancyInput = IRLibLoader.load('/js/fancyInput.js');
    var geoComplete;
    if(googleAPI.ready()){
      geoComplete = IRLibLoader.load('/js/jquery.geocomplete.min.js');
    }

    if(googleAPI.ready() &&
       fancyInput.ready() &&
       geoComplete.ready()){
      console.log('All ready');
      this.next(); // Render the page when all the libraries are ready

      // Testing this here
      if(Meteor.isClient){
        console.log("Meteor.isClient");
        IRLibLoader.load('/js/landing.js');
        // Set places autocomplete
        Template.landing.rendered = function(){
          $('section :input').val('').fancyInput()[0].focus();
          $('section :input').geocomplete();
          console.log("loading.js ejecutandose (after render)");
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But when I browse `localhost:3000`, the layout gets rendered, the googleAPI, fancyInput and geocomplete libraries are loaded too since the 'all ready' message gets printed at console, and landing.js also gets loaded (since it loads the background image and the message 'Meteor.isClient' also gets printed).

But then, the 'landing' template never gets rendered. Its content does not appear, and the console message inside the `Template.landing.rendered` never gets printed. This is the `template.js` file:

```
<template name="landing">
  <img id='logo' src="img/logos/logo.png">
  <div id='content'>
    <section class='input'>
      <div>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Type text here'>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
```

I also tried loading landing.js with onAfterAction, which seems to happen before the onBeforeAction according to the Firebug console. How strange!

I can't understand why the template is not being loaded, since no error appears at meteor console. Any idea?

EDIT: it does work if I remove the layout, which looks like this:

```
<template name="layout">
  <head>
    <title>Welcome to my app</title>
  </head>
</template>
```

What's wrong with this layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think you might be overthinking this a little.  Why not use existing packages for these libraries?  Aside from being significantly easier to use, some of that 3rd party code would get minified into the main app js file instead of making additional HTTP requests to download them.

For example, [dburles:google-maps](https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/google-maps) gets you the Google Maps API and extra libs of your choice (with the option to only load on specific routes) and [jeremy:geocomplete](https://atmospherejs.com/jeremy/geocomplete) gets you Geocomplete (which automatically installs that maps package as a dependency).  See the jeremy:geocomplete [README](https://atmospherejs.com/jeremy/geocomplete) for implementation.

As for Fancy Input, why not [create a simple Meteor package](https://atmospherejs.com/i/publishing) wrapper for that so you can just `meteor add fancy-input`?

Also, your `Template.landing.rendered` callback should not be in an `onBeforeAction`.  Ideally, it should be in its own file with other code for the landing template.

Comment: I know I can (and should) use packages. But for those cases where a package will be used on one page and not at the rest of the pages (I'm obviously talking about a multipage webapp), I think this is the way to go, at least for the landing.js script, since I don't want that code to be executed at other routes.

Anyway, current problem is that the template is not being loaded. Even if the landing.js is placed at /lib/ or /client/ and I let its execution automatically, the template should be rendering now. So where is the problem?

Comment: You get this `console.log("Meteor.isClient");` ?? or not even that?

Comment: @Ethaan yes, I get that after the console.log('All ready'), but the code inside the renderer callback never gets executed. I have also tried moving that block of code to /lib/landing.js, and it gets executed before any other console.log from router.js (i guess because alphabetical order when loading the js files inside /lib/), but the rendered callback never gets executed either. That's what I can't understand

Comment: hmm weird i never use the `isClient` a before, what happened on this **2 thing first** put the `this.next();` at the very bottom of the `onBeforeAction` and **second** escenario if you put `this.next();` inside the rendered did you get the warning console "did you forget to call this.next();'

Comment: @Ethaan I got the 'did you forget to call this.next()' message until the 'All ready' message is printed. Then, the this.next() call is executed. But the template does not get rendered.

The template has an image and an input field, and none of them appears at the page. In addition, the rendered callback does not get called, so I assume the template is not being rendered at all. It is placed at /client/template/application/landing.js. I updated the question with template contents, just in case

Comment: @Roman Rdgz  what happend if you take the ifClient outside the onBefore function? You say that the render dosnt wait to the files correct?

Comment: @Ethaan after some try-error, I finally found that the problem is the global layout used at the Iron Router. If I remove it and use the route template without a layout, it works. I will try to update this evening the question adding the layout code, just in case I made some terrible mistake, but it is so simple that it's strange. Isn't it legit using a layout and a then also a template? I thought that was what the Discover Meteor book taught.

Comment: @Ethaan I have updated the question adding the layout code. Could you have a look and explain why it does not work if I include it?

Comment: You are missing the {{> yield}} helper